Presence not updating in Microsoft Teams using Graph API setUserPreferredPresence endpoint
We have developed an MS Teams Tab app. One of its features allows users to set their MS Teams status directly from our app. We use the setUserPreferredPresence endpoint of the Microsoft Graph API to update the status. While this functionality generally works well, we have encountered an issue when a user sets their status to "Away" in MS Teams and remains inactive for more than 15-20 minutes. In this scenario, when we call the Graph API to update the status using setUserPreferredPresence, we receive a 200 OK response from Graph, but user's status does not change in Teams.
Our API call to the Graph API looks like this: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${ids}/presence/setUserPreferredPresence. This works for other statuses but fails when trying to update from "Away."
any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Could you include how you are running the API call? Are you using token generated with client credentials flow or using Graph Explorer?

@Sridevi, We are using User Delegated permission scope. Once user grant us permission, we save the refresh_token. We are generating the access_token from the refresh_token and use it to set the presence.

We used user deleted permission token because we wanted any user from organization to be able to grant the permission. App-only tokens need Admin permissions.
@Sridevi Also, as I said, it work if user is active on screen and we try to change it. The issue only comes, if they are not active for more than 10 minutes and then if we try to change the status from our app.

Preferred presence takes effect only when at least one presence session exists for the user. For presence session, you need to either create it using set presence API call or make sure user is logged in to MS Teams client. Try calling  set presence API before updating status.

As mentioned in this MS Doc,

Preferred presence takes effect only when at least one presence session exists for the user. Otherwise, the user's presence shows as Offline.

For presence session, you need to either create it using set presence API call or make sure user is active by logging into MS Teams client.
I registered one application and added API permissions of Delegated type like this:

Initially, I created both tokens using authorization code flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope:Presence.ReadWrite offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

Now, I used this refresh token to generate new access token after some time with below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id:appID
client_secret:client_secret
refresh_token: 0.AbcAmPlsIszdBUCs //paste the refresh token that you got above
scope: Presence.ReadWrite

Response:

In the case where user is not active for more than 15-20 minutes, make use of set presence API call first to create presence session like this:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/presence/setPresence
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "sessionId": "appId",
  "availability": "Away",
  "activity": "Away",
  "expirationDuration": "PT1H"
}

Response:


Note: When a user presence changes in Microsoft Graph, because the Teams client uses poll mode, it will take a few minutes to update the presence status.

You can also run below API call to check the user's presence status after few minutes that changed to Away successfully like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/presence/

Response:

Reference:
presence: setPresence - Microsoft Graph v1.0 

thanks for the detailed response. I will try it and let you know. Thanks
